# Get SQL after Zend\Db\Sql\Select

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, tablegateway

I'm on zend framework 2.

The scenario is, I want to know the actual SQL query after `Zend\Db\Sql\Select`. I cannot use `Zend\Db\Sql\SQL` here, and

```
$select = new Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
$select->where(array($between));
$select->prepareStatement($select)->getSQL();
```

is giving error like,

> Call to a member function getParameterContainer() on null

What is the correct way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [getSqlString()](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/Sql/AbstractSql.php#L40) method.

More info you can find here: https://akrabat.com/displaying-the-generated-sql-from-a-zenddbsql-object/